# Java.lang.NullPointerException al ejecutar un programa. (Parece un problema de configuración)

Tags: java, eclipse, jpa

Soy nuevo tanto en la comunidad SO como en programación y quería saber si alguien con más experiencia me puede ayudar.

El problema es el siguiente:

Arranco el pc y ejecuto eclipse de forma normal, doble click, selecciono el workspace y enter de nuevo. Al cargarse los proyectos veo que todos tienen el aspa roja que indica que hay algo que **NO** funciona bien.

Primero pensé que eran fallos en el código pero ya de por sí me extraña, ya que el ultimo día que utilicé Eclipse funcionaba sin problemas. Reviso cada clase de cada proyecto y no encuentro fallo alguno, salvo en un par de proyectos JPA, ya que estamos aprendiendo JPA y los mapeados todavía no los domino.

He estado buscando por la web a ver si encontraba el problema pero lo único que he encontrado han sido referencias a la configuración de eclipse, ya que el fallo no se muestra a través de consola, si no que es un mensaje de la aplicación.

Dejo fotos para su mejor comprensión. Muchas gracias de antemano a cualquier persona que pueda ayudarme o al menos lo intente.

Gracias de nuevo.

Imagen de inicio de eclipse: [image: Típico mensaje de Eclipse cuando hay algún error en el proyecto][image: Y este es el error definitivo que muestra el sistema al ejecutar cualquier clase de cualquier paquete de cualquier proyecto]

Comment: Hola @Borja, bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español. Habitualmente estos problemas ocurren cuando se corrompe la carpeta con la configuración del workspace o de los metadatos de la aplicación. Puedes intentar descargando una versión de Eclipse, seleccionando otro workspace diferente al que tienes con esta versión e importando alguno de los proyectos que tienes aquí

Comment: Dale click derecho a un proyecto-> Build path-> Configure Build path y revisa que este bien direccionado java en la carpeta libraries, si se actualizo java automaticamente posiblemente haya quedado en otra ruta con otro update, o se haya quedado corrupta la instalación de java

Comment: Muchas gracias a los dos por la pronta respuesta. El problema reside en la última actualización de java, ha debido corromper algún archivo de configuración. He reinstalado el jdk y ahora no me abre eclipse diciendo esto: a java runtime environment (jre) or java development kit (jdk) must be available in order to run Eclipse. No virtual machine was found after searching the following directions:"Aquí la ruta del jdk" seguiré probando cosas a ver si lo soluciono. Muchas gracias de nuevo!!

Comment: Ya he conseguido arrancar el programa y los proyectos funcionan como es debido. No se como cerrar el hilo ni como puntuar vuestras respuestas, ya que las dos me han servido para dar con el problema. Este ha sido que al instalar la nueva versión de java, por algún motivo que desconozco, ha corrompido los archivos de configuración. La solución ha sido desinstalar el jdk, volver a instalarlo y agregar al archivo .ini en la carpeta de eclipse la ruta hacia el jdk, doble click al icono de eclipse y a funcionar. Muchas gracias por vuestra ayuda!!

Comment: @Borjinha10 a que nadie ha agregado una respuesta, puedes agregar una respuesta tú mismo, los demás de la comunidad te ayudaremos a que sea una buena respuesta, te recomiendo leer el artículo [¿Cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)